# How to get the list of all the issues in a project in JIRA using REST API?

Tags: jira-rest-api

I am trying to get the list of all the issues irrespective of their status in a JIRA project.

I am doing a GET requset to the following URL:

```
https://jira.org.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project={projectID}&issuetype=all
```

But, this doesn't return all the issues in response.

Where am I going wrong? Is the URL format above wrong?

Comment: The above url seems fine, and should work
for more detaild on JQL look here : https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/about-the-jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-query-issues?_ga=2.103153219.2134195711.1513226279-157956123.1501743941

Comment: Thanks for the link. I made a little adjustment and it works fine now.  `https://jira.org.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project={projectID}&fields=issue,status,name&startAt=0&maxResults=8000`